# Filtering MS Graph query for Planner Tasks

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am querying ms graph for planner tasks https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Planner/Plans/PlanID/tasks

This returns all the tasks in planner. I am hoping to filter these tasks by 'createdDateTime' greater than equals to last month. OR 'percentComplete' is less than 100.

New to querying data, so I am unsure what syntax to use. I was hoping to use $top= x would be based on createdDateTime. but if I use this

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/Planner/Plans/planID/tasks?$Top=20

it still returns all of the tasks.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Planner doesn't support filters at this time. The recommended approach is for the client to read the data and filter on the client side.

For general filtering and query parameters, this documentation should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?view=graph-rest-1.0